# Modularize shiny code that has multiple output IDs

Tags: r, shiny

I have a number of outputIDs in a Shiny app:

In the example below, I have only three outputIDs

```
SERVER:
outIDs <- paste("text",1:3) 

lapply(list("text1", "text2", "text3"), function(x){

  output[[x]] <- renderText({
    switch(x,
          "text1" = "This is text 1",
          "text2" = "This is text 2",
          "text3" = "This is text 3"
           )
     })
    })

UI:
 lapply(outIDs), function(x) htmlOutput(x))
```

It render ok,, but If I have like 30, what is the best way to compress the code? I tried this

```
SERVER:
outIDs <- paste("text", 1:30) 
outText<- paste("This is test", 1:30)

 for (i in 1: length(outIDs ){
output[[outIDs[i]]] <- renderText({
outText[i]
  })

UI:
 lapply(outIDs), function(x) htmlOutput(x))
```

By the above approach, it renders the this:

"This is text 30" "This is text 30"

.... 30 times.

Instead, I want:

"This is text 1".
"This is text 2"
...
"This is text 30"

Help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the following (using `lapply` instead of a for-loop):

```
library(shiny)

outIDs <- paste("text", 1:30)
outText <- paste("This is test", 1:30)

ui <- fluidPage(lapply(outIDs, function(x)
  htmlOutput(x)))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  lapply(seq_along(outIDs), function(i) {
    output[[outIDs[i]]] <- renderText({
      outText[i]
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As an alternative you can use `local({ })` to make the loop work (See the following link).
[Here](https://gist.github.com/bborgesr/e1ce7305f914f9ca762c69509dda632e) you can find some information regarding reactives and loops in shiny.

In example 3 Joe Cheng explains the behaviour regarding the for loop as follows:

```
# --- Joe on this behavior:
# --- > It's because all the iterations of the for loop share the same
# --- > reference to el. So when any of the created reactive expressions 
# --- > execute, they're using whatever the final value of el was.
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Any idea why the for loop didn't work?

Comment: Yes, it is explained in the gist i linked. I copied the according statement to my answer.